# Is a photo editor or vector graphics software essential for 3D creation and Modeling

Tags: texturing

I am new to blender and I am trying to build my skill. I am curious as to whether learning an addition raster or vector-based graphic software is essential in Blender, as I feel there are some textures that I feel may need. or is it possible to find all I need online? I don't want to spend time learning photoshop while I could be using that time improving my blender skill

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a rule.  In fact there are no rules at all here. It depends on what you want to do. No software is essential in digital art. You can use whatever you want or like and whatever gives you the desired results. With that said it is a fact that photo or image editing software is extremely useful when working with 3d.

Having worked with Photoshop almost every single day of my life for the last 15 years or so I can say... that it does not necessarily need to be Photoshop :D . It's a good and popular choice, but you can definitely find good or even better alternatives. You can choose Krita, Affinity Photo, Gimp or even do some painting straight in Blender, but Photoshop will do as well. Or don't choose at all, use all of them that you can get your hands on. As for you not wishing to spend time on it... Well I would recommend not to think too much about it. You will not waste that time and you should be prepared to spend loads and loads of time if you are learning CG anyway. The main concepts are pretty similar in most image editing software packages and will be useful whatever you choose. In 3d graphics context, image editors are relatively simple, so it's definitely not a bad idea to just choose one and learn it. Don't make a big deal out of it.

Comment: I'm really enjoying your answers to these opinion-based questions :). Nothing beats personal experience.

Comment: I was having a real battle with myself if I should break the rules here, but decided to just go wild here. :D

Comment: Yes. You will need additional tools once you get deeper into 3D, but it will depend on your needs. Some of the tools in blender are quite mature, others not so much. There are no tools to paint, modify or reformat pixel based/raster images in blender, so you will need to use a paint program.
Vector/Curve editing in blender is not great compared to other mature and specialized vector drawing programs out there. It will be easier to work in those first and import curves into blender.

Creating maps, textures and UVs in blender is possible, but there are plenty of more efficient tools as well.